# Custom CSS lines connecting multiple divs/progress bars

Tags: css, svg

I want to create rounded lines that connect 3 divs together like the image below. I tried using css border radius but not sure how to make them look connected like image below.

```
<div class="progress bar"> 29</div>

<div class="box"></div>

<div class="progress bar"> 28</div>

.box{
  width:500px; height:100px;  
  border:solid 5px #000;
  border-color:#000 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100px 100px 0 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try pseudo element like this :

```css
.progress {
  position:relative;
  margin:50px;
  padding:5px;
  border:5px solid blue;
  width:20px;
  border-radius:50%;
  text-align:center;
  background: #fff;
}
.right:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 15px;
    right: -38px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-right: 5px solid blue;
}
.left:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 15px;
    left: -38px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-left: 5px solid blue;
}
.dotted-left:after {
  border-left: 5px dotted blue;
}
.dotted-right:after {
  border-right: 5px dotted blue;
}
.dotted-progress {
  border-style:dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress right"> 29</div>
<div class="progress left dotted-left"> 28</div>
<div class="progress dotted-progress"> 28</div>
```

Comment: Is it pretty compatible with  most browsers versions?

Comment: @DavidHope thanks ;) i think it always good to rely on pseudo elements, easier to handle and avoid us a lot of html (even if it's a lot of CSS)

Comment: @condo1234 yes, as you can see i only used very basic property. no transformation or animation or any complicated stuffs

Comment: @condo1234 this is a very basic idea, all you have to do is to play with values and add more property to achieve your needs ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
/* Rotate from top left corner (not default) */
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
-moz-transform-origin:    0 0;
-ms-transform-origin:     0 0;
-o-transform-origin:      0 0;

-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
-moz-transform:    rotate(90deg); 
-ms-transform:     rotate(90deg); 
-o-transform:      rotate(90deg);
```

Here is a working Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/20x3ejz3/

You can play around with the sample code to achieve the desired result but this will give you a starting point.